# Datamap insert data array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with inserting data via an array to populate the datamaps map.

My code is this, but it keeps giving me error, they don't like the for loop inside i.bubbles

```
(function($) {
"use strict"

var i = new Datamap( {
    scope: "world", 
    element: document.getElementById("world-map"), 
    responsive: !0, 
    geographyConfig: {
        popupOnHover: !1, 
        highlightOnHover: !1, 
        borderColor: "transparent", 
        borderWidth: 1, 
        highlightBorderWidth: 3, 
        highlightFillColor: "rgba(0,123,255,0.5)", 
        highlightBorderColor: "transparent", 
        borderWidth: 1
    }, 
    bubblesConfig: {
        popupTemplate: function (e, i) {
            return '<div class="datamap-sales-hover-tooltip">' + i.country + '<span class="ml-2"></span>' + i.sold + "</div>"
        }, 
        borderWidth: 0, 
        highlightBorderWidth: 3, 
        highlightFillColor: "rgba(0,123,255,0.5)", 
        highlightBorderColor: "transparent", 
        fillOpacity: .75
    }, 
    fills: {
        Visited: "#777", 
        neato: "#777", 
        white: "#777", 
        defaultFill: "#EBEFF2"
    }
});

i.bubbles([
    for(x=0; x<(length.array); x++){

        {
            centered: "DEU", fillKey: "white", radius: 5, sold: "75-sdjfbvksfnd", country: "German"
        },

    },
]),
window.addEventListener("resize", function (e) {
    i.resize()
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You are getting an error because you are putting a `for` loop inside an array, where a value is expected. What is `length.array`? What is the purpose of the `for` loop?

Comment: Why not use the `for` loop to create an array, then pass that array to `i.bubbles`? Might as well use a more descriptive variable names too...

Comment: my array is declared above, this is a function that generates the data for me for the map.
The for the moment I wanted to see if at least I populate one since the array has a value.